# Значение слова "уявиться"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

В письмах Елены Рерих, написанных в 30-е годы прошлого века, встречается странное слово **уявиться**, понять смысл которого никак не получается.

Например: *Приближающаяся к нашей Системе Планета **уявится** на стабилизации в нашей Системе*.
Или: *Таким образом, это новое пространственное тело **уявилось** огромным конгломератом сил, или энергий, и стало Солнцем*.

Причем, иногда она употребляет форму "уявиться", а иногда "оявиться".
Подскажите, пожалуйста, это какое-то ее личное слово или оно действительно имело место в русском языке? И, соответственно, что это слово означает?

Comment: Мне  кажется,  что  это  её  личное  слово.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приставки **О-**, **У-** к слову *явиться* — устаревшие, из старославянского языка, развились из юса большого, ранее они означали движение от вероятного, предполагаемого к реальному состоянию, из современных приставок к ним близка ПРО- (проявляться), в украинском языке осталось значение "предположительно, вероятно".
http://www.diary.ru/~rusjaz/p182962957.htm

В русском слово в таком значении просто исчезло, осталось ЯВЛЯТЬСЯ — сделаться явным, видимым, реальным, т.е. проявляться.

Попробуем применить: "Приближающаяся к нашей Системе Планета проявится на стабилизации в нашей Системе" или "Таким образом, это новое пространственное тело проявилось огромным конгломератом сил, или энергий, и стало Солнцем".

Answer (score 2):

Интересный факт обнаружился. Моя трехлетняя племянница, изображая из себя фокусника, говорила : "Смотрите - я появляюсь и уявляюсь".  А писем Елены Рерих она не читала)

Comment: Ну,  она - то  правильно  приставками  пользуется.

Answer (score 1):

Можно откинуть индивидуальные приставки! Остаётся "явится" - станет реальностью.

Речь идет о триаде мировосприятия - одновременном сосуществовании трёх миров: реального, загробного и идеального... То бишь Яви, Нави и, предоложительно, Прави.

О виртуальном существовании которых свидетельствуют долгоиграющие лексические следы: 
ЯВЛЕНИЕ, ЯВНЫЙ, ЯВСТВЕННЫЙ, НАВИЙ, НАВАЖДЕНИЕ (кстати, одна из частей "Операции Ы...) - и ПРАВДА, ПРАВЫЙ со всем сопутствующим рядом.

Comment: Смысл-то  понятен  в  общем.  Речь  о  применении  приставок у-  и  о-  в  одном  значении.